Use argument value as type key in declaration file
I'm working to create a Prisma extension. For reasons, I started with JavaScript, using JSDoc hints for typing. The extension actually works just fine; however, the type hints are terrible, which led me to believe I was doing something wrong. In fact, when I switched to a typescript transpiler, all sorts of errors appeared in my declaration files that were invisible when using esbuild. My biggest current challenge in squashing these is, I need to use a value provided by the user when the initial extension is instantiated as a key in various other type declarations in my declaration files.
For example:
//file: index.d.ts
import { MyMethod1Args } from './method_1.d.ts';

// these are mocks; really imported from Prisma
type SomeType = 'id' | 'foo';
interface SomeOtherType {
  foo: string;
  bar: number;
}

export interface RequiredArgs {
  modelName: string;
  idFieldName?: SomeType; // want to use user value of this as key elsewhere
}

// what I want to do
export type IdField = Pick<SomeOtherType, `${idFieldName}`>;
export type IdFieldKey = keyof IdField; // maybe typeof keyof IdField?

export declare function myExtendsion<I extends RequiredArgs>(args: I): {
  Method1(args: MyMethod1Args): string
}

That (retrospectively misguided) attempt to use a Template Literal, is where I'm trying to create a type definition which depends on the user input. There are a few dozen of these across the code.
The reason to have it this way is, as I mentioned, the JavaScript is already working, and already "typed" with JSDoc hints, and I'd like to migrate it, but slowly — not having to rewrite every JS file up front. Right now, those JSDoc hints are imported from other declaration files, so I need to be able to use those IdField and IdFieldKey in other places. For example:
//File: method_1.d.ts
import { IdFieldKey } from '$type/index.d.ts';

// trying for MyMethod1Args = { foo: { in: string[] } },
// where "foo" was the value supplied to `idFieldName`.
export type MyMethod1Args = {
  [K in idFieldKey]: { in: string[] }
};

Note: This may or may not be relevant to the answer, but I'm including it here in the event that it impacts things, and to help explain how this is actually being used. What I've done in the JavaScript is before exporting the individual methods from the main function, I use a HoF to wrap them all and pass in the top level args as configArgs, so that each method has access to the parameters (e.g., idFieldName. But I don't include that in the function signature, so it's not confusing in the Intellisense or whatever.
// File: Method_1.js
/**
 * @param {import('$types/method_1.d.ts').MyMethod1Args} args
 * @returns string
 */
export default function (args, configArgs) {
    console.log(args[configArgs.idFieldName].in.join());
}


@jonrsharpe, you removed the typescript-generics tag. It's true, I didn't use the word "generics" anywhere in here, but isn't it inherent to what I'm attempting?

• Unless this question depends on prisma, please [edit] the code to be a [mre] that doesn't rely on third-party types to demonstrate. We should be able to copy and paste it into our own IDEs and work on it without pulling in extra stuff. Also, please use conventional namings; custom type names should be in UpperCamelCase. • What type do you expect idFieldName to be? Is it just K in that example? If so, why not use K? If not, what is it? Also, {[K]:⋯} should be {[P in K]:⋯} or Record<K, ⋯>. But without a [mre] I'm just guessing. So please [edit] to provide that.

@jcalz, Done! I put it up on codesandbox. Valid values for idFieldName are dependent on what was provided for modelName. Hopefully the minimal example clarifies.

A [mre] needs to be in the question as plaintext, not just as an external link. It's great to link to an IDE project but it should also be here as text as well, or it doesn't count.  When I look at that link I see errors unrelated to what you're asking, like export type X; without a definition, etc. Could you make sure that the only problems present are the ones you're asking about?

(see prev comment) I also can't see how the example answers my questions. When I look at K extends InitArgs<M> ? K extends undefined ? 'id' : \${idFieldName}` : never;I am baffled. IfK extends InitArgsthenKis definitely *not*undefined(becauseInitArgsis an interface), so'id'is never reached. Why then are you writing that? This cannot be a [mre] because it's not minimal, and that's before I even get to`${idFieldName}`, which I still don't get. Could you provide some sample intended input-output pairs for that type? It depends on modelName`, but how?

(see prev 2 comments) I think it would be best if you just write a very simple example that shows the inputs and the intended outputs, and then someone can write a type function for you that does it, instead of trying to debug or understand your unsuccessful attempts, which might be more of a distraction than an aid to understanding. Could you [edit] to do that?

OK @jcalz; I've tried one more time with an even more minimal example, and tried to be as explicit as possible. Hopefully this clarifies.

The thing about a [mre] is we need to be able to copy and paste it into our own IDEs and start working on it. My IDE doesn't know about PrismaModelProps or a bunch of other stuff in there so I have to either try to build that up myself, or ignore it. If I ignore it and just look at "if a user calls MyExtensions" at face value I'd get something like this playground link. Is that close enough to what you want to serve as an answer? If so I'll write up an answer. If not, please [edit] to make a true [mre] that demonstrates what I'm missing.

That looks like pretty much exactly it, assuming the two different args ({ modelName: string, idFieldName?: K } and { [P in K]: boolean } are in a .d.ts declaration file! (and if you can explain howPropertyKey is working in your playground, that would be great!)

I posted an answer explaining; we might want to [edit] the question to clean it up. It shouldn't look like a series of edits (interested parties can view the revision history to see previous stuff) and it shouldn't contain pieces we're not really asking about unless they are a true [mre] in the question itself (so the link to extra code is extraneous). I'm happy to do it myself, if you don't mind. Let me know.

Hmm this question looks quite different, now. What does "I'm trying to create a type definition which depends on the user input" mean? On the face of it it's impossible. What "user" is inputting things before compile time? Is that the person writing TypeScript code?

(see prev comment) The more I re-read this question the more baffled I'm becoming about what you're trying to do. What is the difference between IdField and IdFieldKey?  I really need to see an example of this thing being used.

To address the MyExtension example in the question without worrying about the relationship between modelName and idFieldName, I'd write a declaration like this:
declare function MyExtension<K extends PropertyKey = "id">(
    arg: { modelName: string, idFieldName?: K }
): {
    MyExtensionsMethod(arg: { [P in K]: boolean }): Promise<void>;
}

Here the function is generic in K, the type of idFieldName. This type is constrained to PropertyKey (which is just an alias of string | number | symbol, precisely the types which can be keys for properties), and which defaults to id (the default will only happen if K cannot be inferred, i.e., when no argument is passed for idFieldName).
Then it returns an object with a method accepting an argument of type {[P in K]: boolean} which is the same as Record<K, boolean> using the Record utility type. It's a simple mapped type that has a property with key of type K and value of type boolean (and is presumably what you meant by {[K]: boolean}).
Let's test it out:
const UserMethods1 = MyExtension({ modelName: 'foo', idFieldName: 'bar' });
const newValue1 = await UserMethods1.MyExtensionsMethod({ bar: true });
    
const UserMethod2 = MyExtension({ modelName: 'foo' });
const newValue2 = await UserMethod2.MyExtensionsMethod({ id: true });

Looks good. For UserMethods1.MyExtensionMethod a {bar: boolean} is expected, whereas for UserMethod2.MyExtensionsMethod an {id: boolean} is expected.
If you need to relate modelName to idFieldName you can presumably make this doubly generic so that you have
declare function MyExtension<M extends ModelNames, K extends KeysFor<M> | "id" = "id">(
    arg: { modelName: M, idFieldName?: K }
): {
    MyExtensionsMethod(arg: { [P in K]: boolean }): Promise<void>;
}

where ModelNames and KeysFor are properly defined, but I'm going to consider that out of scope here, since that part should be easy enough to hook up.
Playground link to code

1st: amazing help, thanks for working through this! 2nd: your answer works as advertised, but isn't quite there, because I need the actual types exported. Re-wrote the question 1 more (and hopefully final) time.

Oh well I guess I have to look at what is essentially a new question and write a different answer? The new version of your question now seems to want... a circular module dependency? And what "user" is deciding what \${idFieldName}`` is supposed to be? I am baffled how the question seems to have mutated out from under me. I thought I understood what you were doing and spent time on writing an answer which looks... useless now? Oh well.

Actually, marking this as correct. The only extra step I needed to get me all the way there was the Parameters utility type.
